# Jquery increase ID of select input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the ID of my select field
The select field is generated by PHP.

The select input field is stored in `var indirectSelect`

As simple as it looks like, I can't change it.
This is what I tried:

```
$(indirectSelect).attr('id', 'indirect_'+counter);
```

HTML stored in `var indirectSelect`

```
<select name="indirect" id="indirect_0" class="form-control">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="8002">Controle ( indirekt )</option>
  <option value="9000">Indirekte uren produktie afdeling</option>
  <option value="9010">Leerschool</option>
  <option value="9020">Opleidingen en trainingen</option>
  <option value="9050">Div. indirekte taken</option>
  <option value="9075">Systeembeheer</option>
  <option value="9900">Stroomstoring</option></select>
</select
```

Complete code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    var regex = /^(.*)(\d)+$/i;
    var indirectSelect = '<?php echo $select_6 ?>';

    $("#addExtraRow").on("click", function () {
        $(indirectSelect).attr('id', 'indirect_'+counter);

        var newRow = $("<tr id="+ counter +">");
        var cols = "";

        cols += "<td><div class='tooltip12'>";
        cols += "<input type='number' id='resourceid_<?php echo $ii; ?>' name='resourceid' class='form-control' value='' readonly>";
        cols += "<span class='tooltip12text'><div id = 'resourcedescr_" + counter + "''></div></span>";
        cols += "</div></td>";

        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="base' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="lot' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="split' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="sub' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="seq' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td>'+indirectSelect+'</td>';
        cols += "<td><input type='date' id='datum_" + counter + "' name='datum' class='form-control' value=''></td>";
        cols += "<td><input type='time' step = '1' id='clockin_" + counter + "' name='clockin' class='form-control' value='' ></td>";
        cols += "<td><input type='time' step = '1' id='clockout_" + counter + "' name='clockout' class='form-control' value=''></td>";
        cols += "<td><input type='number' id='break_" + counter + "' name='break' class='form-control' value='' step='.01'></td>";
        cols += "<td><input type='number' id='worked_" + counter + "' name='worked' class='form-control' value='' readonly></td>";
        cols += "<td><input type='number' id='multiplier_" + counter + "' name='multiplier' class='form-control' value='100'></td>";

        cols += '<td><button class="btn btn-default resetRow" type="button"><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>';
        cols += '<button class="btn btn-outline btn-default ibtnDel" type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>';
        cols += "</tr>";

        newRow.append(cols);
        $("table.extraFormRows").append(newRow);
        counter++;
    });

    $("table.extraFormRows").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();       
        counter -= 1
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `indirectSelect` is simple string from PHP

Your `$(indirectSelect)` converts string to jQuery object in memory, but you never use it again.

Try:

```
$("#addExtraRow").on("click", function () {
   var $indirectSelect = $(indirectSelect);
   $indirectSelect.attr('id', 'indirect_'+counter);

   ...

   // Wrap element in another element to get full inner HTML, otherwise it would be just <option> tags
   cols += '<td>' + $indirectSelect.wrap('<div>').html() + '</td>';
```

Comment: This will give only <option> tags

Comment: @RicoKrouweel When doing `.html()` you get inner HTML of element. That's why you need to wrap element to some other element and then get this wrapper HTML